# Spring Rest Controller not able to validate path variable when request body is also passed in addition to path variable

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I've a rest controller and one of the endpoint looks like this:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/myapi/{id}", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<MyEntity> myApi(
          @Valid @PathVariable("id") @NotBlank String id,
          @Valid @RequestBody MyRequestPayload myRequestPayload) throws Exception)
{
  LOGGER.info("Id is {}",id);
  ...............
  .........................
  .............................
}
```

For some reason, when I call the API with an empty or null path variable and a request payload, the path variable is not failing the validation and the control comes inside the method block.
What am I doing wrong? Kindly advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Valid` validates complex objects, containing fields annotated with constraint annotations.

For this case, you need to use `@Validated`:

> The `@Validated` annotation is a class-level annotation that we can use to tell Spring to validate parameters that are passed into a method of the annotated class.

So mark your controller class as `@Validated`, which would trigger the validation of the `id` path variable.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/my")
@Validated
public class MyController {

  @PostMapping(value = "/myapi/{id}", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<MyEntity> myApi(
      @PathVariable("id") @NotBlank String id,
      @Valid @RequestBody MyRequestPayload myRequestPayload) throws
      Exception {
    LOGGER.info("Id is {}", id);
  }
}
```

Reference: [Validation with Spring Boot](https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/#validating-path-variables-and-request-parameters)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works like a charm. I've added the v@Validated annotation on the class-level.
However given it's annotated at the class level, will it have any side-effect on the other API end-points that we have within the controller class. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @Sandy I have used it on many projects and haven't encountered any side effects yet. If this answer solved your problem can you consider accepting it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, This answer solves my issue. I'll consider it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `@Valid` annotation with a String object.

String has no "valid" state.

If you don't want it to be null or blank you may use `@NotBlank` instead.

Comment: Seems I missed adding the @NotBlank annotation in the original question. I've edited the code snippet, but still the control is getting inside the method block

Comment: How are you testing it?

Comment: Using postman as a rest client

Comment: I mean how you actually calling the endpoint (url, params, body, header...). In Postman you have a translation to _curl_ on the right side, if you want to share.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the @Valid and try using @PathVariable(value = "id",required = true) and @RequestBody(required=true)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. Also I think both path variable and requestBody required attributes are true by default.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).